# Nested If Loop Compile Error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have am getting a compile error for the below nested If function. This has to be something easy that I'm just missing can you spot the compile error?

```
If reduce_amount > 0 Then For Each rCell In HBWS.Range(Cells(3, Tickercolumn), Cells(LastHBR, Tickercolumn))
    If rCell.Value = TTB And rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> TickerTotalString And reduce_amount > 0 Then
    Cell_value = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If reduce_amount < Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell_value - reduce_amount
        ElseIf reduce_amount > Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        reduce_amount = reduce_amount - Cell_value
        ElseIf reduce_amount = Cell_value Then
        reduce_amount = 0
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        End If
    End If
Next
End If
```

Would also appreciate an explanation as to what is causing the compile error to prevent this from happening in further iterations.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error, on which line? And there are alot of variables or what look like variables with no declarations shown.

Comment: `For Each ...` should be on its own line

Comment: Alex K is right, split the `If`and the `For` statements. Beside this, indent your code correctly to see such errors

Comment: hahah I knew it was silly, just needed an extra pair of eyes. If you include that into answer and add a little context ill accept it.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering and closing this question - following Alex K comment

```
Sub test()
If reduce_amount > 0 Then
    For Each rCell In HBWS.Range(Cells(3, Tickercolumn), Cells(LastHBR, Tickercolumn))
    If rCell.Value = TTB And rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> TickerTotalString And reduce_amount > 0 Then
    Cell_value = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If reduce_amount < Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell_value - reduce_amount
        ElseIf reduce_amount > Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        reduce_amount = reduce_amount - Cell_value
        ElseIf reduce_amount = Cell_value Then
        reduce_amount = 0
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        End If
    End If
Next
End If
End Sub
```

*Marked answer as community wiki*